# IntelliJ Idea 12: How do I auto import namespaces?

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I can hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> shortcut to auto import namespaces. How do I do it in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition?

Comment: Gist of shortcuts [IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse Shortcuts](https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/) `ctrl+alt+o`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Code > Optimize Imports` will provide you the behavior you are after. If you want to adjust the settings you can so via `Settings > Editor > Auto Import`.

[image]

Comment: Works great. However, it isn't the same with Ctrl + Shift + O. With the key combination, I can just use anytime I want. For this case IntelliJ, the closest I can do is to make it "Optimize import on the fly".

Comment: Is there an option to import all classes in file at once?

Comment: @alaster I am searching for such an option myself, it looks like we are going to miss this option from Eclipse until IntelliJ implements it as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can type <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to show a dropdown of possible classes to auto-import, it's similar to Eclipse.

I found this in Android Studio on Mac OS X - if I mouse over the class name it can't find, you get a suggestion pop-up that shows this shortcut

Comment: I try the `Code > Optimize Imports`, but  not work,. this answer is the only one available

Comment: Why there is no option to import all classes in file?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: "`Ctrl+Alt+O`" .
[image]

Comment: That does not work: it just cleans up the imports that are already there

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ ShortCut depends on Keymap:

[image]

You can customize shortcut for your favorite commands.