# Automatically refactor wildcard imports into explicit imports in IntelliJ (for Scala/Java)

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Consider the code below.

Is it possible to make InteliJ to automatically refactor each wildcard import into explicit imports (whatever is used in scope)?

For example `import scalatags.JsDom.all._` into `import scalatags.JsDom.all.{ol,li,div}`?

My search suggests that it is not possible, but maybe I am wrong?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348816/intellij-never-use-wildcard-imports) is a related but different question.

```
package app.client

import app.client.components.RootReactComp
import app.client.pages.spatutorial.components.GlobalStyles
import japgolly.scalajs.react.ReactDOM
import org.scalajs.dom
import org.scalajs.dom.raw.Element

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSExport
import scalacss.Defaults._
import scalatags.JsDom.all._
import scalatags.JsDom.implicits._
import scalatags.JsDom.svgAttrs.{fill, height, points, stroke, width,strokeWidth}
import scalatags.JsDom.svgTags._
@JSExport("Main")
  object Main extends js.JSApp {
@JSExport
         def main(): Unit = {
    //    log.warn("Application starting")
    //    // send log messages also to the server
    //    log.enableServerLogging("/logging")
    //    log.info("This message goes to server as well")

    // create stylesheet
    GlobalStyles.addToDocument()
    // tell React to render the router in the document body
    //ReactDOM.render(router(), dom.document.getElementById("root"))
    ReactDOM.render(RootReactComp.themedView(), dom.document.getElementById("joco"))
    val el: Element =dom.document.getElementById("svg-example")
     val l=     div( ol(
       li("Ordered List Item 1"),
       li("Ordered List Item 2"),
       li("Ordered List Item 3")
     )).render
  val s=    svg(height := "800", width := "500")(
                polyline(
                    points := "20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180",
                    fill := "none",
                    stroke := "black",
                    strokeWidth := "3"
                  )
           )
    el.appendChild(l);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that worked for me - however sub-optimal:

1. Optimize imports
2. Go to any import .* and press alt-enter (a menu-question will appear to replace the * import with individual imports) then press enter again.
   [image]

Comment: alt-enter on wildcard imports comes up with nothing on Android Studio Dolphin

Comment: This is possible, I was using Intellij... However, the library was in the path right? (e.g. it could autocomplete the java.<ctrl-tab>) ... Otherwise....

Answer (score 0):

Open Dialog

```
Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Scala
```

Select tab `Imports`

In the field "Class count to use import with _", enter a ridiculously high number, e.g. 5000.

From now on, the "Optimize Imports" command will resolve wildcards to individual imports.

You probably also want to activate

```
Editor > General > Auto Import > Scala > Optimize Imports on the Fly
```

Comment: Thanks that was the first thing I tried, it did not work. Does it work for you ? I am on Mac, maybe there is some difference. Version 2016.3.4, result : https://snag.gy/Ca8jXK.jpg with settings : https://snag.gy/WSNolB.jpg

Comment: @jhegedus - It didn't work for me at first - until I realised that at some point a re-install of intelliJ had reset the "Class count to use import with *" setting back to the default of 5. Changing it to "9999" then made ctrl-alt-O work.