# Default imports from sun instead of java package in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea2017

My current system(MacOS 10.10.5) configuration is :

> ```
> IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2
> #Built on 9August,2017
>
> java version "9"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
> ```

Every time I start working on a project(currently 1.8.0_65) and write a class using

```
List<String> example = new ArrayList<>();
```

=> If I click on the auto suggested tip for `List` => Import class

The default import statement introduced is

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;
```

while I expect it to be :

```
import java.util.List;
```

**Is there any configuration that I can redress or is this some bug in the combinations I am using? Would want to know what settings has given preference to `sun` package over the `java` package?**

***Note*** : Have gone through the answer of [Any way (or shortcut) to auto import the classes in IntelliJ IDEA like in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211842/any-way-or-shortcut-to-auto-import-the-classes-in-intellij-idea-like-in-eclips) but the options that I get when I type `List` doesn't include the one from `java.util` in my case.

***Edit*** : The import for `java.util.List` is not missing, I am able to import the same manually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had an issue like this with `java.util.Arrays` not showing up in completion lists. Turns out I had somehow added it to the import and completion exclusion list.  My finger must have slipped in a quick action popup at some point.

Maybe the same thing happened to you.  Open your Settings dialog and find your way here:

[image: Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import]

Then, look for this list of Excluded imports:

[image: Exclude from Import and Completion]

See if `java.util.List` shows up in that list, and if so, remove it.

With `java.util.List` excluded, `com.sun.tools.javac.util.List` might be the only other `List` type in your class path.  If you have the "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" option enabled, IntelliJ would then import the `sun` class without even asking.

Comment: It just could be so painful sometimes when you don't realize what had just changes with few button press and mouse clicks. Thanks for debugging this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such option to prefer a package over another for importing classes.

Instead, you could exclude `com.sun.tools.javac.util.List` from auto import. To do so, in `Class to Import` window, click on the arrow on the right, then `Exclude com.sun... from auto-import`:
[image: exclude auto-import popup]

After that, `java.util.List` should be the first choice of import. If later you need to remove some excluded imports, you can go to **Preferences** › **Editor** › **General** › **Auto Import** to find them.

Comment: *java.util.List should be the first choice of import.* its not even a choice for now is what my concern is. I dnt want to deprioritize the `sun` package import anyway.

Comment: Maybe try to uncheck `Add unambiguous imports on the fly` option in **Auto Import** settings?

Comment: Is `java.util.List` the only missing import from the JDK? Do you have `Optional` or `Double`?

Comment: Its not a missing import, I can still manually add it to the imports. Would add this info in the question

Comment: @nullpointer Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import, then in the 'Java' section look for a list entitled "Exclude from Import and Completion".