# Howto get IntelliJ to auto-import when using javadoc {@link}?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211842/any-way-or-shortcut-to-auto-import-the-classes-in-intellij-idea-like-in-eclips) explains how to enable auto-import settings. I did so, but when I type

```
/** some javadoc where I want to {@link SomeClass}
```

it doesn't do what I want. Upon typing `SomeClass` IntelliJ shows me the potential link targets, all fine. I select one, and press enter. To then look at:

```
/** some javadoc where I want to {@link x.y,z.SomeClass}
```

What I would like instead:

```
import x.y,z.SomeClass; 
...
/** some javadoc where I want to {@link SomeClass}
```

In other words: how do I make IntelliJ to auto-import classes for @linking instead of using the fully qualified class name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `Preferences > Code Style > Java > Imports`, uncheck `"Use fully qualified class names in javadoc"`.

Comment: Now, that was quick. Thank you!